# Entering a while loop when the condition is false

Tags: java

I'm currently working on an RPG where you gain experience after killing an enemy. Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
this.experience_current += experience;
while(this.experience_current >= EXPERIENCE_MAX);
{
    System.out.println(this.experience_current >= EXPERIENCE_MAX);
    levelUp();
    this.experience_current -= EXPERIENCE_MAX;
}
```

What's happening here is that, upon enemy death, this method is called to add experience to the player's current experience total. This total is then compared to the level up experience, and if the total is above the max, we level up and reduce the total by the max. It's in a loop to assure big values of experience (like from a boss) can cause us to level up multiple times.

The problem I'm having is that this loop should not be running when it is. Upon killing my first enemy and getting 3 experience points (with a max of 100), this method is called. The condition is not met, but we enter the while loop anyway. The System.out.println(...) line is printing "false" to the console to confirm that the condition is broken, but nevertheless, we're here.

I'm not doing any type of multi-process programming here, so I can't imagine the total value is being changed to a value that makes the loop condition correct. Really - I'm at a loss for why we're entering the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a superfluous semi-colon at the end of your `while`. Remove it and your loop shall work.

Comment: Wow. Didn't even see that. That fixed everything. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see it at first either. It would be nicer if for/while loops needed braces always.

Comment: A proper configured IDE can warn you about an empty loop body and/or unnecessary braces.

Comment: @Tom Obviously, but how many beginners have a properly configured development environment?

Comment: A few, I know, but I don't see the point in restricting Java (enforce a body for loops) just because some can't configure their IDE. And yes I know that you just said "it would be nicer" and nothing more specific :P.